# make python variable triple quotation style

Tags: python, html, css, parsing

I am trying to parse a html which has class name like class="link", my problem is a want to read every line in variable then parse it, but it should work with triple quotation, how can I make a string variable with triple quotation style. Thanks.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()

var = open('./index.html','r')
strings = var.read()



parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
        '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Well, if I read the content from a local file, how can I parse the strings var?

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>hello world</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, excepturi, consequatur sed nobis facere veritatis tempore qui ipsum enim dignissimos!</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I read this html as a big string, how can I parse it, I just want get the content in h1 tag. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post an example and explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by triple quotation style? Do you just want to be able to have newlines and quote characters in your input?

Comment: Your code seems fine, it runs (omitting the file read part, since I don't have your `index.html` file).  What's the question?  Can you provide an example of the problematic input you described?

Comment: Opps, I don't try it, it works for me. Thanks for your time again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   h1 = false

   class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
       def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
          ## print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
          if tag == 'h1':
                 h1 = true
       def handle_endtag(self, tag):
          ## print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
          if tag == 'h1':
                 h1 = false
       def handle_data(self, data):
           ## print "Encountered some data  :", data
           if h1:
                 print data
```

Comment: That is want I want. Thanks for your time.